# Get error selenium python : unable to locate element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting this error while trying to click on a tag
. python3 - selenium - firefox

```
 unable to locate element /html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]
```

my code:

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://gamehag.com/news')
articles=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]')
articles.click()
```

Comment: Which element you are looking for  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to click on first article induce `WebDriverWait`() and  wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
driver.get("https://gamehag.com/news")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".row.news-container.tile-grid.small-gutters a"))).click()
```

---

If you want to get list of articles then use `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and then get the `href` value and iterate

```
driver.get("https://gamehag.com/news")
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".row.news-container.tile-grid.small-gutters a")))
urls=[element.get_attribute('href') for element in elements]
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    #do something
```

Note: you need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```